# XML Serialization Circular Reference

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

In my application I use the following code to serialze objects:

```
    private static string Serialize(Type type, object objectToSerialize)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        using (TextWriter writer = new StringWriter(builder))
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(type);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, objectToSerialize);
        }
        return builder.ToString();
    }
```

This code just worked fine until now.

We've introduced a new class which looks like:

```
    [Serializable]
    public class Restriction 
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public ResticType Type { get; set; }
        public Restriction Parent { get; set; }
        public List<Restriction> Children { get; set; }  
    }
```

If I try to serialize it I get the following exception:

```
A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type Restriction
```

I already found out, that this occures because of the Parent and the Children which are also of type `Restriction`

I've already tried to set the Parent-Property to `NonSerialized` but this doesn't work.

Unfortunately I can not change the code for serialization...

What can I do to serialize this class?

Actual my only idea is to implement `IXmlSerializable` in my Restriction-class and do the reading and writing of the xml by my own. I hope there is another way...

Answer (score 2):

> I've already tried to set the Parent-Property to `NonSerialized` but this doesn't work.

`NonSerialized` is for binary serialization. Use `XmlIgnore` instead.

Note that you'll have to manually restore the `Parent` property after deserialization:

```
void RestoreParentRelationship(Restriction restriction)
{
    foreach (var child in restriction.Children)
        child.Parent = restriction;
}
```

Comment: When do I have to call `RestoreParentRelationship`?

Comment: Restoring the parent will not be that easy. If you are not the receiver of the serialized data then each client will need to do the restore. This is out of your reach.

Comment: @Tomtom after deserializing the Restriction object